# Maemo kernel boot

Tags: kernel, boot, maemo

I have a Nokia N900. I reflashed it and installed u-boot. Then was trying to install NITDroid, and messed up something. Now I can access u-boot console, but cannot start Maemo.

I have been able to extract the kernel image from the original system file (used for flashing). Put the kernel on a sd card and created a script (boot.scr) which runs it. The kernel starts, but hangs and eventually reboots.

Now I need some advice on how to setup the system in order for the kernel to run successfully.

Comment: did you follow this guide: https://leste.maemo.org/Nokia_N900
... the equivalent worked for me on a Droid 4